# Unable to modify javascript within an HTML website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, edit

Hello I am relatively new and have never coded before a month ago but I am slowly teaching myself the structure and inner workings of a website though html, css, and javascript. I am trying to modify a specific script within a website. This website is

https://www.wizards.com/dnd/dice/dice.htm

My goal is to make it so that I can manipulate a dice roll to give me an altered range for example instead of 1-4, maybe 1-10 and to also perhaps give me a number I specify. I also want to leave the general aesthetic of the site as unchanged as possible.

So first off I put this handy piece of code within the URL
javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0

and it allowed me to make the content within the body editable.

I wanted to be simple and just change the D4 dice element https://gyazo.com/adf563827f63edd37264882e90fd5f85 so it would give give me numbers in a range of 1-20.

The HTML code for this element is

```
<a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="rolld4()"><img src="https://www.wizards.com/dnd/dice/images/d4a.jpg" alt="d4" name="d4" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('document.d4','document.d4','images/d4b.jpg')" width="38" border="0" height="37"></a>
```

I noticed the onclick="rolld4()" So I looked within the head of the website and noticed within `<script language="JavaScript1.2"></script>` these lines of code.

```
function rolld4() {

   d4rolls = parseInt(document.form1.d4n.value);  
   d4mod = parseInt(document.form1.d4mo.value);  
   dtotal = "";
   d4res = 0;
   rtotal = document.form1.runningtotal.value; 

    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        if (document.form1.d4m[i].checked) {
        d4pm = i }
    }

    if (d4pm == 0) {
        dtotal = dtotal + "Roll(" + d4rolls.toString() + "d4" + ")+" +  d4mod.toString() + ":\n" 
    }   

    if (d4pm == 1) {
        dtotal = dtotal +  "Roll(" + d4rolls.toString() + "d4" + ")-" +  d4mod.toString() + ":\n" 
    }   

    for (r=0; r<d4rolls; r++) {
       var d4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);    
       d4res = d4res + d4;  
       dtotal = dtotal + d4.toString() + ","    
    }

    if (d4pm == 0) {
       d4res = d4res + d4mod;   
       dtotal = dtotal + "+" + d4mod + "\n" + "Total:" + d4res  
    }   

    if (d4pm == 1) {
       d4res = d4res - d4mod;
       if (d4res <= minimumvalue) {
          d4res = minimumvalue;
          } 
       dtotal = dtotal + "-" + d4mod + "\n" + "Total:" + d4res  
    }   

   document.form1.d4r.value = d4res;    
   rtotal = dtotal + "\n\n" + rtotal;  
   document.form1.runningtotal.value = rtotal;  

}
```

I altered above line `Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1)` to `Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1)`

I then created a new script with the modified code and placed it below the D4 dice element which should alter the output to give me my range from 1-20. I was able to achieve a bit of success and did in fact mimic a roll range of 1-20. However this has only worked for me once and I have been unable to replicate it even going through the exact same process.

I also saw that within the `<script language="JavaScript1.2"></script>`scripts that it was one large comment. This is what confuses me because if the javascript functions within the code are turned to comments where is the javascript being pulled from when the dice is clicked and "rolled". I cant seem to find the source.

I am a total novice when it comes to javascript I have mostly been delving into HTML and CSS for designing websites so I have practically zero knowledge of javascript beside the general format.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter (change) or delete any javascript on a loaded website. It's not possible as web browsers first compile the javascript when website is loading and prepare it for execution. 
Even if you delete a script tag, that piece of code exists somewhere in the memory.

BUT, you can add pieces of javascript code to a webpage (think of it as it is adding itself to the end of the page in a separate script tag) via web console or Scratchpad in Mozilla Firefox OR developer tools > console in Google Chrome.

With that and some clever thinking (depending on the existing code on the website) you can do the stuff you want.

Comment: Yeah i was worried that something like that was the case, if you don't mind I have a question like I said I added a new script yet it did not work. Is their anyway I can make a new script which sort of supersedes an old one, i.e. the original.

Comment: I think not. You can just attach new code which will be executed with the old one (with the same level of priority).

Comment: Thanks again for the help, and the clarification. I think i know what I have to do and will play around with the code.